# How to plot a vertical line every X step in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

This might be really basic, but how can I plot a vertical line from Y= 0 to Y = plot-y-max every X time step ? I used `if ticks mod 100 = 0 [plotxy ticks plot-y-max]` but its not working.

Can anyone please help me with this simple problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your approach to:

```
if ticks mod 100 = 0 [
  plot-pen-up
  plotxy ticks 0 
  plot-pen-down
  plotxy ticks plot-y-max 
]
```